# activating a dockerized host

Tags: docker, docker-machine

### My question is how can I activate a dockerized host?

**My docker-machine version is 0.12.2.**

---

For example, I create a docker machine using "`docker-machine create --driver virtualbox host`" and now I want to set my docker client to run against the host machine that I just created.
And I don't want to use the builtin commands like "`eval $(docker-machine env host)`"..

There is a command I recently saw which is "`docker-machine use (machine_name)`" but unfortunately it requires docker-machine version of 0.14 which I don't have nor I can download cause of the Adminstrator name and password(I don't have them)!!!

Hope I was clear!!

Comment: wow, no answer yet!

Comment: What's wrong with `eval $(docker-machine env)` that you don't want to use it?

Comment: the exercise that i am trying to answer, says that you can't use any builtin commands. eval is a builtin command!!

Comment: This is impossible without using `eval`, `export`, or `.`, which are all shell built-ins.